# Problemas ao criar aplicativo para consumir serviços dos Correios

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que tem o objetivo de consultar preços e prazos de encomendas consumindo o serviço dos Correios. Porem estou com dificuldades de implementar o serviço no aplicativo. Como faço para transferir os dados das entradas da primeira activity(onde pego cep origem e cep destino) da segunda(Comprimento, largura, altura,peso, diametro e recuperar na terceira, para realizar entao a consulta do serviço usando o método dos correios. 2

```
package com.example.diego.precoeprazocorreios;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Encomenda implements Serializable{

private String cepOrigem;
private String cepDestino;
private int idIcon;
private String codigo;
private String PrazoEntrega;
private String peso;
private String maoPropria;
private String avisoRecibo;
private Double comprimento;
private Double altura;
private Double largura;
private Double valorDeclarado;

public Encomenda(String cepOrigem, String cepDestino, int idIcon, String codigo, String prazoEntrega, String peso, String maoPropria, String avisoRecibo, Double comprimento, Double altura, Double largura, Double valorDeclarado) {
    this.cepOrigem = cepOrigem;
    this.cepDestino = cepDestino;
    this.idIcon = idIcon;
    this.codigo = codigo;
    PrazoEntrega = prazoEntrega;
    this.peso = peso;
    this.maoPropria = maoPropria;
    this.avisoRecibo = avisoRecibo;
    this.comprimento = comprimento;
    this.altura = altura;
    this.largura = largura;
    this.valorDeclarado = valorDeclarado;
}

public String getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}

public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}

public String getPrazoEntrega() {
    return PrazoEntrega;
}

public int getIdIcon() {
    return idIcon;
}

public void setIdIcon(int idIcon) {
    this.idIcon = idIcon;
}

public void setPrazoEntrega(String prazoEntrega) {
    PrazoEntrega = prazoEntrega;
}

public String getPeso() {
    return peso;
}

public void setPeso(String peso) {
    this.peso = peso;
}

public String getMaoPropria() {
    return maoPropria;
}

public void setMaoPropria(String maoPropria) {
    this.maoPropria = maoPropria;
}

public String getAvisoRecibo() {
    return avisoRecibo;
}

public void setAvisoRecibo(String avisoRecibo) {
    this.avisoRecibo = avisoRecibo;
}

public Double getComprimento() {
    return comprimento;
}

public void setComprimento(Double comprimento) {
    this.comprimento = comprimento;
}

public Double getAltura() {
    return altura;
}

public void setAltura(Double altura) {
    this.altura = altura;
}

public Double getLargura() {
    return largura;
}

public void setLargura(Double largura) {
    this.largura = largura;
}

public Double getValorDeclarado() {
    return valorDeclarado;
}

public void setValorDeclarado(Double valorDeclarado) {
    this.valorDeclarado = valorDeclarado;
}

public String getCepOrigem() {
    return cepOrigem;
}

public void setCepOrigem(String cepOrigem) {
    this.cepOrigem = cepOrigem;
}

public String getCepDestino() {
    return cepDestino;
}

public void setCepDestino(String cepDestino) {
    this.cepDestino = cepDestino;
}


}
```

Primeira activity

```
package com.example.diego.precoeprazocorreios;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnProximo1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.proximo1);
    btnProximo1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            validarCampos();
        }
    });
}

public void validarCampos() {

    EditText cepOrigem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.origem);
    EditText cepDestino = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.destino);

    String cepOri = cepOrigem.getText().toString();
    String cepDes = cepDestino.getText().toString();
    String padrao = "\\d{8}";

    if (!cepOri.matches(padrao)) {
        cepOrigem.requestFocus();
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CEP inválido", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    } else if (!cepDes.matches(padrao)) {
        cepDestino.requestFocus();
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CEP inválido", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    } else {
        Encomenda enc = new Encomenda(cepOrigem.getText().toString(), cepDestino.getText().toString());
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SegundaActivity.class);
        myIntent.putExtras("objeto", enc);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Não sei se entendi bem, mas se necessita, na 3ª  Activity, dos valores passados pela 1ª Activity à 2º Activity, faça a 2ª Activity passá-los a ela.

Comment: Eh isto que estou tentando agora... do jeito que esta ai ela nao captura as entradas.

Comment: @ramaral agora ja esta pegando os valores das entradas, como faço para passar esses dados para a tela seguinte? lembrando que eu preciso pegar somente o que o usuario escolher, exemplo se ele escolhe o formato da encomenta caixa/pacote, sera preciso passar as entradas de largura, altura e comprimento. Minha duvida esta justamente ai, como fazer isso de maneira dinamica de acordo com que o usuario escolhe

Comment: Mais uma vez não tenho a certeza do que quer. Se percebi correctamente você anda lá perto. Deve criar apenas um bundle com `new Bundle()` depois vá acrescentando valores a ele de acordo com as opções escolhidas pelo usuário. Deverá também acrescentar um valor(flag) para indicar o tipo de valores: por exemplo 1 indicará caixa/pacote. No final adicione o Bundle ao intent que abrirá a Activity seguinte. Nessa activitie, em função da flag, obtenha os valores passados.

Comment: Eu penso que ele quer passar os dados de uma activity para outra, como uma wizard, e no final ele vai usar todos os dados. Eu faria diferente do que usar Bundle(), passando um model para as activities e depois consumiria este model na última.

Comment: @ramaral criei só um budle como pediu e passei a flag e o valor de cada uma das entradas que quero passar pra terceira tela, porem chega nulo ta terceira tela. Resumindo o que quero agora, é pegar todos os valores de entrada da primeira e segunda tela e passa-las pra terceira, que é la onde farei a requisição do serviço dos correios.

Comment: voce tem algum exemplo pratico dessa maneira @GrupoCDSInformática?

Comment: @CarlosDiego tem uma resposta simples, no SOen, [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2736612/7762411)

Comment: @GrupoCDSInformática sim é uma possível abordagem e haverá certamente outras. Apenas não quis fugir ao que o AP estava a fazer para não adicionar mais confusão.

Comment: @ramaral sim sim, é que eu acho mais prático passar o model, e tira a necessidade de ler muita coisa do bundle. Mas o massa do SO é a possíbilidade de ver inúmeras soluções para um problema, isso é o que mais curto ;)

Comment: @GrupoCDSInformática é isso mesmo que quero fazer. Vou tentar aplicar o metodo na minha aplicaçao.

Comment: @GrupoCDSInformática estou com dificuldade de implementar o metodo, ja criei a classe e implementei serializable, na minha primeiraActivity instanciei o objeto Encomenda, porem ele reclama do construtor, pois sao varios parametros, e na primeira tela eu so pego dois que sao o cep origem e destino.

Comment: Cria um construtor padrão, e vai setando as informações usando os gets e sets da classe. Lembrando que você vai somente instanciar ela na primera activity, e mandar ela de uma activity para outra.

Comment: `Encomenda enc = new Encomenda(cepOrigem.getText().toString(), cepDestino.getText().toString());
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SegundaActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtras("objeto", enc);
            startActivity(myIntent);` Assim?

Comment: @GrupoCDSInformática no exemplo que vc indicou o cara usa numa mesma tela, somente dois parametros, como seria aplicado no meu caso, estou sem saber aplicar. Reformulei a pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acrescente ma sua classe um construtor assim:

```
public Encomenda() {
}
```

Depois que você preencher os campos e for chamar a outra activity, preencha os campos usando o get e set. Coloca esse trecho no else:

```
else {
        Encomenda enc = new Encomenda();
        enc.setCepOrigem(cepOrigem.getText().toString());
        enc.setCepDestino(cepDestino.getText().toString());
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SegundaActivity.class);
        myIntent.putExtras("objeto", enc);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
```

Ai, na outra activity, você ao preencher os outros campos, antes de chamar a activity ler essa variavel do bundle, preencher com os novos campos usando o get e set e depois passar para a próxima, como da primeira para a segunda. Exemplo:

```
Encomenda enc = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("objeto");
enc.setComprimento(); //Ai le do EditText como na primeira Activity.

//Aqui vc vai chamar a activity 3
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TerceiraActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtras("objeto", enc);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Na TerceiraActivity, você vai ler do mesmo jeito que na segunda, preencher e passar para a chamada do webservice.

Comment: pronto, fui justamente o que fiz. Agora estou com outro problema, nao consigo capturar os valores de entrada. Vou atualizar a pergunta pra tu ver

Comment: Ao invés de atualizar, crie uma outra pergunta com o codigo dela certinho, pois o problema ai é outro, e vai bagunçar ficar atualizando.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/253913/conversao-string-para-double-retornando-null