# Conversao String para Double retornando null

Tags: java, android

Estou com uma aplicaçao em android que preciso capturar as entradas e armazenar no meu objeto Encomenda, porem preciso converter as entradas(Strings) em numeros Double, porem da o seguinte erro: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String. Onde estou errando?

```
package com.example.diego.precoeprazocorreios;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class SegundaActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {

private TextView vLarguraCX;
private TextView vAlturaCX;
private TextView vComprimentoCX;
private EditText vLarguraCX1 ;
private EditText vAlturaCX1;
private EditText vComprimentoCX1;
private SeekBar vPeso;
private Button btnProximo2;
private TextView kilo;
private TextView vlarguraEnv;
private TextView vComprimentoEnv;
private EditText vLarguraEnv1;
private EditText vComprimentoEnv1;
private TextView vDiametroRolo;
private EditText vDiametroRolo1;
private TextView vComprimentoRolo;
private EditText vComprimentoRolo1;
private RadioGroup RadioGroup1;
private TextView txtDeclaracao;
private EditText valorDeclaracao;
private int progress_value;
Encomenda enc = new Encomenda();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_segunda);

    RadioGroup1 = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rg);
    //Variáveis de entradas para o PACOTE
    vLarguraCX = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.larguraCaixa);
    vLarguraCX1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.larguraCaixa1);
    vAlturaCX = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.alturaCaixa);
    vAlturaCX1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.alturaCaixa1);
    vComprimentoCX = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.comprCaixa);
    vComprimentoCX1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.comprCaixa1);
    //Variáveis de entradas para o ENVELOPE
    vlarguraEnv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.larguraEnv);
    vLarguraEnv1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.larguraEnv1);
    vComprimentoEnv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.comprEnv);
    vComprimentoEnv1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.comprEnv1);
    //Variáveis de entradas para o ROLO
    vDiametroRolo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.diametroRolo);
    vDiametroRolo1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diametroRolo1);
    vComprimentoRolo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.comprRolo);
    vComprimentoRolo1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.comprRolo1);
    //Checkbox e radioButtons
    txtDeclaracao = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtValorDeclarado);
    valorDeclaracao = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.valorDeclarado);
    btnProximo2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.proximo2);
    final CheckBox chmaoPropria = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.maopropria);
    final CheckBox chDeclaracao = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.declaracao);
    final CheckBox chAR = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.AR);
    RadioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    seebar();

    //Verifica se o checkbox Aviso de Recebimento foi clicado
    chAR.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(chAR.isChecked()){
                txtDeclaracao.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                valorDeclaracao.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                enc.setAvisoRecibo(valorDeclaracao.getText().toString());
            }else{
                txtDeclaracao.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                valorDeclaracao.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
    //Verifica se o checkbox Mão Própria foi clicado
    chmaoPropria.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(chmaoPropria.isChecked()){
                enc.setMaoPropria("S");
            }else {
                enc.setMaoPropria("N");
            }
        }
    });
    //Verifica se o checkbox Declaração de recebimento foi clicado
    chDeclaracao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(chDeclaracao.isChecked()){
                enc.setAvisoRecibo("S");
            }else {
                enc.setAvisoRecibo("N");
            }
        }
    });
}

public void seebar(){

    vPeso = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.peso);
    kilo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.kg);
    kilo.setText(vPeso.getProgress() + "kgs / " + vPeso.getMax() + "kgs");
    vPeso.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            progress_value = progress;
            kilo.setText(progress + "kgs / " + vPeso.getMax() + "kgs");
            enc.setPeso(String.valueOf(progress));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            kilo.setText(progress_value + "kgs / " + vPeso.getMax() + "kgs");

        }
    });
}

public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

    //Verifica se o radioButtom Caixa foi clicado
    if(checkedId ==  R.id.caixa){
        //Exibe os campos referentes a caixa
        vLarguraCX.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        vLarguraCX1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        vAlturaCX.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        vAlturaCX1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        vComprimentoCX.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        vComprimentoCX1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //Oculta os demais campos
        vlarguraEnv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        vLarguraEnv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        vComprimentoEnv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        vComprimentoEnv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        vDiametroRolo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        vDiametroRolo1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        vComprimentoRolo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        vComprimentoRolo1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        vLarguraCX1.getText().toString();
        vAlturaCX1.getText().toString();
        vComprimentoCX1.getText().toString();
        enc.setFormato(1);
        enc.setLargura(Double.parseDouble(vLarguraCX1.getText().toString()));
        enc.setAltura(Double.parseDouble(vAlturaCX1.getText().toString()));
        enc.setComprimento(Double.parseDouble(vComprimentoCX1.getText().toString()));

        //Verifica se o radioButtom Envelope foi clicado
    }else if(checkedId == R.id.envelope) {
        //Exibe os campos referentes a envelope
        vlarguraEnv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        vLarguraEnv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        vComprimentoEnv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        vComprimentoEnv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //Oculta os demais campos
        vLarguraCX.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        vLarguraCX1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        vAlturaCX.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        vAlturaCX1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        vComprimentoCX.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        vComprimentoCX1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        vDiametroRolo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        vDiametroRolo1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        vComprimentoRolo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        vComprimentoRolo1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        enc.setFormato(2);
        enc.setLargura(Double.valueOf(vLarguraEnv1.getText().toString()));
        enc.setComprimento(Double.valueOf(vComprimentoEnv1.getText().toString()));


        //Verifica se o radioButtom Rolo foi clicado
    }else if(checkedId == R.id.rolo) {
        //Exibe os campos referentes a rolo
        vDiametroRolo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        vDiametroRolo1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        vComprimentoRolo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        vComprimentoRolo1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //Oculta os demais campos
        vLarguraCX.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        vLarguraCX1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        vAlturaCX.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        vAlturaCX1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        vComprimentoCX.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        vComprimentoCX1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        vlarguraEnv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        vLarguraEnv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        vComprimentoEnv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        vComprimentoEnv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        enc.setFormato(3);
        enc.setDiametro(Double.valueOf(vDiametroRolo1.getText().toString()));
        enc.setComprimento(Double.valueOf(vComprimentoRolo1.getText().toString()));
    }

    btnProximo2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(SegundaActivity.this, TerceiraActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("objeto", enc);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Saida: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ao que parece a string está vindo vazia

Comment: @AndersonHenrique so nao sei o pq. Nao consigo encxergar o erro ai.

Comment: Ele diz que é na segunda activity linha 166, pode me falar o nome da string que está nessa linha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você invoca o método `onCheckedChanged` (atrvés das alterações no componente `RadioGroup1`) é provavél que os valores de `vDiametroRolo1` e `vComprimentoRolo1` estajam vazios (conforme dito no comentário da pergunta!), por isso ocorre um erro na conversão!

Pode se corrigir de algumas formas:

**1. Inicializando os valores com `0`.**

Exemplo:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_segunda);

    vDiametroRolo1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diametroRolo1);
    vDiametroRolo1.setText("0"); // iniciamos com zero!
    vComprimentoRolo1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.comprRolo1);
    vComprimentoRolo1.setText("0"); // iniciamos com zero!
   .... 
}
```

**2. Tratar no método `onCheckedChanged`:**

```
        if(!"".equals(vDiametroRolo1.getText().toString())) {
            vDiametroRolo1.setLargura(Double.valueOf(vLarguraEnv1.getText().toString()));
        }
        if(!"".equals(vComprimentoEnv1.getText().toString())) {
            vDiametroRolo1.setLargura(Double.valueOf(vComprimentoEnv1.getText().toString()));
        }
```

> **Qual você deve usar?**

**Isto quem irá responder é sua regra de negócio!**

Se estes valores são obrigatórios, será necessário validar os campos!

Comment: acredito que nao seja bem isso, pois troquei de double para string e pega os valores normalmente. `vLarguraCX1.getText().toString();
            vAlturaCX1.getText().toString();
            vComprimentoCX1.getText().toString(); enc.setFormato(1);
            enc.setLargura(vLarguraCX1.getText().toString());
            enc.setAltura(vAlturaCX1.getText().toString());
            enc.setComprimento(vComprimentoCX1.getText().toString()); `

Comment: o problema é, preciso que essas entradas sejam em double. Mas nao consigo converte-las

Comment: os campos largura, comprimento, entrada e diametro, justamente os que sao double no meu objeto encomenda. Eu coloquei todas essas variaveis como string no objeto, e com o codigo no comentario acima ele pega os valores normal. Agora double, nao funciona

Comment: sim, somente numeros

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68464/discussion-between-carlos-diego-and-thiago-luiz-domacoski).